# JSON with backslash for CURL. Not able to generate Apex request class

Tags: apex, json, curl, jsongenerator

I have a request JSON that other system has given to use. It looks like below:

```
{
  \"list\": [
    {
      \"m1\": \"tval\",
      \"fill\": {
        \"tool\": \"4535\"
      },
      \"respfield\": [
        \"tid\",
        \"tName\"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that it has back slash in front of every key and value. I am unable to parse it directly in https://jsonformatter.org/ with back slashes. When I remove the back slashes and format the JSON I get:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "m1": "tval",
      "fill": {
        "tool": "4535"
      },
      "respfield": [
        "tid",
        "tName"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I used curl command to hit the service with back slash JSON -> returns a response and without back slash JSON- which returns error. My question is how can I use the JSON with back slash to generate an Apex request class that I can serialize. Should I be using the one without back slashes( but the service retruns error when used with curl command)? would JSON serialize and curl behave differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke `curl` from the command line, you have to escape any double quotes that you include within any quoted string. The escaped quotes are interpreted by your shell (probably `bash`), not by `curl` itself or by your remote service.

Your "real" outgoing JSON shouldn't include any backslashes. You should only have those present when you're embedding a JSON payload inside an outer quoted string in a context like `bash` or many other scripting languages.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I thought but dint know the exact reason. So I assume I should be good with generating an apex class from JSON without back slash and using it when doing JSON serialization.

Comment: That is correct.